# Unable to parse XSD because of namespace conflict

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

I am trying to generate Java classes using xjc utility but getting below exception:

> [ERROR] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'act:statusCd'. It
>   was detected that 'act:statusCd' is in namespace
>   'http://www.example.org/account/schemas/' , but components from this
>   namespace are not referenceable from schema document
>   'file:/E:/SpringWebServices/BankWebService/xsd/account.xsd'. If this
>   is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'act:statusCd' needs
>   to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate
>   'import' tag should be added to 
>   'file:/E:/SpringWebServices/BankWebService/xsd/account.xsd'.   line 22
>   of file:/E:/SpringWebServices/BankWebService/xsd/account.xsd

**Here is my XSD:**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:act="http://www.example.org/account/schemas/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/account"  
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="AccountRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="AccountResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AccountNumber" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="AccountName" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="AccountBalance" type="xs:double"/>
            <xs:element name="AccountStatus" type="act:statusCd"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="statusCd">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Active"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Inactive"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong in the XSD file. I want to refer "statusCd" simpleType in my response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the namespace URI corresponding to the `act` namespace prefix from this**

```
xmlns:act="http://www.example.org/account/schemas/"
```

**to this**

```
xmlns:act="http://www.example.org/account"
```

**Then your reference to `act:statusCd` will resolve correctly to the `statusCd` simple type found in the target namespace, `http://www.example.org/account`.**